# Creating DEM from points, contours and drainage network using Kriging interpolation In ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, interpolation, kriging

How to create DEM from points, contours, and drainage network using a kriging interpolation?

The scanned topographic map, with 300 dpi resolution,was georeferenced and manually vectorized using ESRI software package (ArcGIS) and specific extensions. GIS layers containing contour lines, elevation points, and the hydrographic stream network were stored in ESRI shapefile format.

From altimetry data, the digital elevation model (DEM) in GRID format was produced by an advanced geostatistical interpolation techniques such as kriging (Burrough and McDonnell 1998) with a resolution of 10 m.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, your Question isn't a question.  Please **edit** it to contain a great deal more information about *your* environment and what *you* have attempted to solve *your* problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  I have like inputs contours, points of elevation and drainage network files. My prupose is creating a DEM. How? I used Topo to Raster but the result was with a low and flou resoulution. I read that by Kriging interpolation, I can produce a Dem by my inputs. How?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain any new information. As stated by the Tour, your job is to make the best possible question. Comments are reserved for those asking for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. GIS SE is not a tutoring service. You can't just tell us what you need to do; you must tell us what you have *tried* and what problem(s) you have encountered.